# Concatenate numerical values in a string

Tags: string, r, concatenation, paste, cat

I would like to store this output in a string:

```
> x=1:5
> cat("hi",x)
hi 1 2 3 4 5
```

So I use `paste`, but I obtain this different result:

```
> paste("hi",x)
[1] "hi 1" "hi 2" "hi 3" "hi 4" "hi 5"
```

Any idea how to obtain the string:

```
"hi 1 2 3 4 5"
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can force coercion to character for `x` by concatenating the string `"hi"` on to `x`. Then just use `paste()` with the `collapse` argument. As in

```
x <- 1:5
paste(c("hi", x), collapse = " ")

> paste(c("hi", x), collapse = " ")
[1] "hi 1 2 3 4 5"
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use `capture.output` with cat

```
capture.output(cat('hi',x))
[1] "hi 1 2 3 4 5"
```

Answer (score 7):

You use `sprintf`:

```
> x=1:5
> str=sprintf("hi %d",x)
> str
[1] "hi 1" "hi 2" "hi 3" "hi 4" "hi 5"
>
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  This looks like the *opposite* of what the OP is asking.